# Headers are not accepting in wrk.format

Tags: lua, http-headers, benchmarking, wrk

I am trying to post data to API. I am building request every time. and I am adding headers to `wrk.format()` method. The headers are not accepting event though headers type is string.

```
headers = {}
s = {}
request = function() 

 headers["Authorization"] = "key"
 for name, value in pairs(headers) do
      s[1] = string.format("%s: %s", name, value)
 end
 print(s[1])
 print(type(s[1])
 return wrk.format("POST", "/api/", s[1] ,data)
end
```

throwing error :

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API ([string "wrk"]:0: attempt to index field 'headers' (a string value))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Third argument must be a table `headers`.  You've passed a string `s[1]` instead.  Correct example: `wrk.format("POST", "/api/", {["Authorization"] = "key"} ,data)`

Comment: if i use above syntax. even it is throwing error.  bad argument #1 to 'len' (string expected, got table))

Comment: Fourth argument to `wrk.format(.., .., .., body)` must be a string.  Probably your `data` is a table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the entire dictionary to the `format` function

```
return wrk.format("POST", "/api/", headers ,data)
```

in case of mine the headers look like:

```
headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```